# Replacing span element text with color

Tags: html, text, colors

I have below span tag generated by custom tool (I can't ask it to generate in different way)

```
  <span tabindex="0" > FINDME </span>
```

I want to write a script section within  and  to find the text "FINDME" and replace this with :

```
<span tabindex="0" style="color:red">FINDME</span>
```

or

```
<span tabindex="0">
<font color="red"> FINDME </font>
</span>
```

Basically I want to get the text colored. Also since I would have multiple span element coming that way so I had to search by text before replacing it.
I don't know how to code it so any help will be appreciated.

thanks !

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: @Hackerman - no but its already answered

Comment: The answer uses jquery xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will search for all the spans in your code and the one that have the text " FINDME " will get the color replaced. This solution is using jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("span").each(function(){
      if($(this).text() == ' FINDME '){
       $(this).css('color','red');
      }            
    });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wearetamo/mdwkakzz/

Comment: Yes it is , Appreciate it . However I was able to manage this without Jquery in my limited expertise , Good that I found the key tag to perform search  :   <script>
var span3 = document.querySelector('#dashboard_page_3_tab span');
span3.innerHTML = '<font color="red"> XYZ </font>' ;

</script>

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out! You should take a look to jQuery if you haven't it will make your life easier lol.

Comment: The problem is, want to see if this solution could be done without referencing any jquery library ... that is only difference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
<script> var span3 = document.querySelector('#dashboard_page_3_tab span'); span3.innerHTML = '<font color="red"> FINDME </font>' ; </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.